# Pseudo-selectors vs methods

Tags: jquery

Just interested, which one's faster? Couldn't google it up.

For example, `$('li:first')` vs `$('li').first()`

Comment: If you don't care about performance, you're not a programmer. Not interested - just move along.

Comment: I don't care about performance unless it's a serious issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: apparently the parsing of the expression incurs a lot of overhead.
In my [quick benchmark](http://jsfiddle.net/Tigraine/Dzx8u/) `.first()` is a lot faster than using the selector.

Expressions simply boil down to methods on the $.expr object [like explained here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/)

The actual implementation of the :first vs the .first() differ a bit:

Here the code for :first on `$.expr.setFilters.first`

```
function ( elem, i ) {
  return i === 0;
}
```

while `$.fn.first` is simply a shorthand for `.eq(0)`:

```
function () {
  return this.eq( 0 );
}
```

without looking at the actual code I'd implement a first() like this if it wasn't there:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    first: function(a) {
        return $(a).first();
    }
});
```

This also means that :first is simply a filter on a list of elements, while .first() is a reduce operation that's more efficient.

**Update2**: Doh - Should have [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). Since jQuery tries to use native CSS selectors in modern browsers and `:first` is no selector from the CSS spec it will always perform a lot worse than a real selector that can take advantage of the browsers native CSS searching methods (whereas jQuery has to emulate that behavior in JS)

Answer (score 1):

`$('li').first()` is about ten times faster than using `$('li:first')`. 
Tested using `Firefox 3.6`.

```
100,000 iterations:
55,870ms using :first
5,858ms using .first()
```

using this code :

```
$(document).ready (function() {
var i, time = +new Date;
for ( i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) {
$('li:first');
}
console.log ( (+new Date) - time );
time = +new Date;
for ( i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) {
$ $('li').first();
}
console.log ( (+new Date) - time );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but my guess would be that internally it would work the same, so the performance would not differ that much. But I can be completely wrong.